# passing information with button in custom cell

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I am having a hard time passing data through a button in a custom cell. So I have a custom cell, that has a button. In the cell's TableViewCell, the button is declared

```
@IBOutlet var UserEdit: RoundButton!
```

And then in the ViewController that has the custom cell, the button is given an action.

```
@IBAction func EditClicked(_ sender: UIButton) -> Void {

       let indexPath = self.selectedIndex
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditPost", sender: indexPath)


    }

 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cells", for: indexPath) as! ProfileTableViewCell

cell.UserEdit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EditClicked), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
        cell.UserEdit.tag = indexPath.row
        print(indexPath.row)
        cell.UserEdit.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
}
```

And the segue works perfectly, However, I will like to pass the information of the cell that the button is clicked in so I do this:

```
 override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard segue.identifier == "Hello", let chatVc = segue.destination as? SendMessageViewController else {
        return
    }

    chatVc.senderId = self.loggedInUser?.uid
    chatVc.receiverData = self.userpicuid
    chatVc.senderDisplayName = self.userpicuid
    chatVc.username = self.username

           if segue.identifier == "EditPost" {

            if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {
                let vc = segue.destination as! EditPostViewController
                let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
                let Booked = post["title"] as? String
                let Authors = post["Author"] as? String
                let ISBNS = post["ISBN"] as? String
                let Prices = post["Price"] as? String
                let imageNames = post["image"] as? String
                vc.Booked = Booked
                vc.Authors = Authors
                vc.ISBNS = ISBNS
                vc.Prices = Prices
                vc.imageNames = imageNames

                print(indexPath.row)
            }
        }}
```

And in the destination view controller, I have this:

```
 @IBOutlet var Author: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Price: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var Books: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var ISBN13: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var ISBN10: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var CoverType: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var Details: UITextField!

 var Booked: String?
    var Authors: String?
    var ISBNS: String?
    var Prices: String?
    var imageNames: String?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.BookTitle.text = self.Booked
        self.Author.text = self.Authors
        self.ISBN10.text = self.ISBNS
        self.Price.text = self.Prices
}
```

But no information is being passed along when I click the button. The text fields in the destination view controller come out empty.

Comment: how do you get the `selectedIndex`

Comment: You have to use either protocol-delegate or closure to pass data.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik var selectedIndex:IndexPath?

Comment: @dahiya_boy i used the same technique as above to pass data through a button that was created programmatically and it worked. I am not sure how to do it the way you suggested

Comment: Check for the button tag property. Sometimes selected index path may come as nil.

Comment: are you sure , `post["title/Author/ISBN/Price/image"] as? String` contains expected String values ? @juelizabeth

Comment: @Roy I tried to check by making a print statement but it doesn't display my print statement. Do you think the problem is with the segue?

Comment: No , I don't think there is any problem with segue you used so far , i do it often too @juelizabeth

Comment: @Roy I updated my `override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {` in my question because they were other details under it and I am not sure if that is what is making the detail segue not work

Comment: You need to create property type variable in destination controller and then set it value from source controller and  then set textfield value in viewwillappear.

Comment: what if you write `sender : self ` in `perfomsegue()` and remove `if let indexPath = sender as? IndexPath {}`, just for a while @juelizabeth

Comment: You have a guard statement on first line of your `prepare(for:sender:)`, guarding for `segue.identifier == "Hello"`. If identifier matches "Hello", then `if segue.identifier == "EditPost" {` (which is your data transfer code) will never be executed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow these steps to achieve your task easier.
First in your `UITableViewCell` class define a button property like as just bellow the function ..

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

> Add This Line

```
var editBtnClickFunction: (() -> Void)? = nil
```

> After this line add little bit code into your button click action like that.

```
if let onButtonTapped = self. editBtnClickFunction {
        onButtonTapped()
    }
```

> Now Come in your main controller from where you are using `UITableViewDataSource` and `Delegate`

> Inside your `cellForRowAt` function add a another code like that before your `return cell` statement

```
cell. editBtnClickFunction = {
   performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditPost", sender: indexPath.row)
}
```

> Now it's final code in your segue prepare method

```
if segue.identifier == "EditPost" {
if sender != nil {
let index : Int = Int(sender! as! String)
            let vc = segue.destination as! EditPostViewController
            let post = self.posts[index] as! [String: AnyObject]
            let Booked = post["title"] as? String
            let Authors = post["Author"] as? String
            let ISBNS = post["ISBN"] as? String
            let Prices = post["Price"] as? String
            let imageNames = post["image"] as? String
            vc.Booked = Booked
            vc.Authors = Authors
            vc.ISBNS = ISBNS
            vc.Prices = Prices
            vc.imageNames = imageNames
        }
    }
```

Comment: it sadly didn't work but thanks for the effort you put in

Comment: @juelizabeth Can you please tell me where you are stuck in that

Comment: I did exactly what you posted but i get the same result as my question. No data is passed and when I try to check if data is being passed by doing print(Booked) it prints out nothing

Answer (score 1):

change this line as follows

```
cell.UserEdit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(EditClicked(sender:)), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)
```

and change the target method declaration as follows

```
@IBAction func EditClicked(sender: UIButton) -> Void {

   let indexPath = self.selectedIndex
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "EditPost", sender: indexPath)


}
```

Try changing the code as above.

Comment: I did, and it''s still not working, I included a print statement and selectedRow = 0 (I only have once cell)

Comment: try removing @IBAction in function definition (may sound idiotic. but try)

Comment: it didn't make a difference. I updated my `override public func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {` in my question because they were other details under it and I am not sure if that is what is making the detail segue not work

Comment: @juelizabeth put a : while setting the selector for the button

Comment: @juelizabeth modified the answer pls check